# Find to which folder a message was delivered in Exchange Online using powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Exchange Online. I'm tracking a message which a user claims wasn't delivered. With a combination of Get-MessageTrace and Get-MessageTraceDetail I'm able to find that the message was successfully delivered. But there's no information to which folder in outlook that message was delivered. This information is included if using the "Mail flow > Message Trace" option from the GUI. But it takes far too much time, literally hours for a simple trace. Is it possible to get this with powershell?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Get-MessageTraceDetail tells simply "Delivered" if the message was delivered to Inbox. Otherwise it tells "The message was delivered to the Junk Email folder".

Answer (score 0):

What license do you have in O365? If you have the [right license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/threat-explorer?view=o365-worldwide) you can use the Threat Explorer to find that information very easy. You can query by a lot of advanced parameters and the result will return the exact folder/action on delivery. So for example, a message can be 'delivered' to the Inbox, and some time later ZAPed from it (soft deleted) automatically, etc. Otherwise, you can use [`Get-MessageTracking`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetrackingreport?view=exchange-ps) - look at Example 2 specifically.